# Is it possible to know if a method is called in an application?

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to try something but am not aware if its possible. I want my code to listen to a method of a 3rd party application. I am trying to work out when the method is called and also retrieve any arguments passed to that method.

For example, the a method is called in the 3rd party application as below:

```
LoggerClass.LogCreate(LogName, LogDetails)
```

I would like to know when LogCreate is called and then retrieve the information by extracting the LogName and LogDetails strings. I would then parse the 2 strings for my own logger utility.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the CLR Profiling API

Comment: Without having access to the source, I don't believe so. There might be some auto-magic (via reflection) that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Well, if you use .Net 4.5 you can patch the method (Don't remember the exact name) so you can write a method that logs the call and then calls the wanted method.

Comment: @SLaks: everything I am finding on CLR Profiling API looks like C/C++.

Comment: @IAbstract: That sounds right; I don't know how easy it is to write a profiler in C#.

Comment: thanks for the responses everyone. I checked profiling API but it seems to be not c# based.. all win API type calls. I started c# only a few weeks back even though I love it, it gets complicated very quickly. :)

Comment: @noobsauce: if you only started C# a few weeks ago, then writing an API profiler will be very difficult, IMO, especially if you attempt the profiler in C#.

Comment: thanks for the feedback IAbstract. you're right, even after looking at the profiling code, I am not sure what it is doing. I am an intern out of college at a small IT services shop and trying to learn new things so they make me perm so getting a bit optimistic is second nature sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the sort of thing enabled by [Aspect-Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

The wikipedia article linked above suggests that it is supported in C#, but doesn't provide detail.  Perhaps someone else here can - I don't do C# myself...

If you don't find support directly in C#, you might want to look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).